# NetSuite : Auto Populate Line Item in Vendor Bill

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Does anyone here have encounter a bug while auto-populating the line item in vendor bill?
I was trying to auto populate the line item base on my criteria fields.
Field A = Batch No.(A batch consist of items) - This items will only use for tagging.
Field B = Drop-down list of Item Category (consists of Item1, Item2, Item3 per category) - Main Item to be used.
e.g.
Selected the "Batch 1" = Sample Item 1, Sample Item 2, Sample Item 3
Selected the "Category 1" = Item1, Item2, Item3
Line Item will be:
Item1 -- Sample Item 1
Item1 -- Sample Item 2
Item1 -- Sample Item 3
Item2 -- Sample Item 1
Item2 -- Sample Item 2
Item2 -- Sample Item 3
Item3 -- Sample Item 1
Item3 -- Sample Item 2
Item3 -- Sample Item 3

Here's my sample code below:

```
var batchsearch = searchthisbatch(FieldA)
var categorysearch = searchthiscategory(FieldB)
var batchline = batchsearch.length;
var categoryline = categorysearch.length;
for (var bc=0; bc<batchline ; bc++){
    for (var cl=0; cl<categoryline ;cl++){
        var bcode = batchsearch[bc].getId()
        var clitem = categorysearch[cl].getValue('custrecord_categorylist');
        nlapiSelectNewLineItem('item');
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', clitem);
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_branchcode', bcode);
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','location',11);
        nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
    }
}
```

The code just works fine except the `nlapiCommitLineItem('item');`
Does anyone knows other code to commit the line item?

Hoping for your kind consideration and assistance on this.
Thanks in Advance.
<--Newbie here.. Sorry -->

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you post them?  The only way to commit line items is using nlapiCommitLineItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a client script then you need to add two parameters to the `nlapSetCurrentLineItemValue` calls.  Adding `,true, true` will make the calls synchronous. Otherwise what is happening is that those calls are still executing when your code gets to `nlapiCommitLineItem`

You’ll probably also find you need to add a delay after commuting the line. This is a bit maddening as the amount of time is by trial and error and that function is also not synchronous and doesn’t have a callback.